# Angular Material Flex Layout - fit div width to content

Tags: flexbox, angular-material

I've been looking around and found many answers, but none seem to quite fit what I need, I have several divs in a row, and I would like the ones on the left to fit their content only, here is the current example:

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" style="border: 1px solid red">
  <div fxFlex style="background-color: yellow">
    foo
  </div>

  <div fxFlex  style="background-color:aquamarine">
    bar
  </div>

  <div fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="end end">
      some content that might expand to a max-width somehow
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the result:
[image]

I would like to achieve something similar to the image below, by specifying a max-width for the first 2 divs if there is enough content, but if there isn't a lot of content, then to only use the width needed, like so:
[image]

Comment: read this: https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

Comment: I read this before, but for some reason my mind completely dismissed the last example when I saw 'ltr', I thought it was for text direction, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `fxFlex="none"`

```xml
<div fxLayout="row wrap" style="border: 1px solid red">
    <div fxFlex="none" style="background-color: yellow">
     foo
    </div>

    <div fxFlex="none"  style="background-color:aquamarine">
     bar
    </div>

    <div fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="end end">
     some content that might expand to a max-width somehow
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  <div fxLayout="row wrap" style="border: 1px solid red">
    <div fxFlex="0 0" style="max-width: 40px; background-color: yellow">
      foo
    </div>

    <div fxFlex="0 0" style="max-width: 40px; background-color:aquamarine">
      bar
    </div>

    <div fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="end end">
      some content that might expand to a max-width somehow
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9ywiaq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

To make them not grown or shrink you can use this:

```
fxFlex="0 0"
```

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Declarative-API-Overview

And for the max width you can use the same css property:

```
max-width: 40px;
```